# Critical Points of Linear Fractional Transformation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization

So I am currently trying to compute the critical points of the following linear fractional transformation:

\begin{equation} f(x) := \frac{||Ax+b||^2}{c^Tx + d} \end{equation}

where $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix of rank $n$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$, $c \in \mathbb{R}^d$, and $d$ is a scalar. And we are using the notation $||y||^2 = y^T y$.

We can compute derivatives to see
\begin{equation} \partial_{x_i} f = \frac{(\partial_{x_i} ||Ax+b||^2) (c^Tx + d) - c_i ||Ax+b||^2}{|c^Tx+d|^2}  \end{equation} so we need to solve

\begin{equation} (\partial_{x_i} ||Ax+b||^2) (c^Tx + d) - c_i ||Ax+b||^2 = 0 \end{equation} and we can use $\partial_{x_i} ||Ax+b||^2 = 2 \langle A_i, Ax - b \rangle$ to simplify this into

\begin{equation}2 \langle A_i, Ax - b \rangle (c^Tx + d) - c_i ||Ax+b||^2 = 0 \end{equation} where $A_i$ is the $i$th column of $A$ and we are using $\langle x,y \rangle = x^Ty$.

I am having trouble computing the critical point. Can I please get some help with simplifying this expression?

Comment: Why are you calling this a linear fractional transformation?

Comment: Here is a [related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4459276)